# Issue with dlopen and weak symbols

Tags: shared-libraries, dlopen

> I have the following sequence
>
> executable (main) ---- (dlopen)---> libapp.so ---(dynamically linked)--> libfoo.so
>
> libfoo.so in turn dynamically links to libfoo_strong.so. libfoo.so invokes a function from 
>   libfoo_strong.so, but also has a weak definition (within foo.c which is compiled into libfoo.so).
>
> Now, libapp.so invokes a function from libfoo.so (say invoke_foo_func_ptr() and this function >invokes a function pointer which stores the symbol that is defined as weak. My expectation is that >invokes_foo_func_ptr invokes the strong symbol, but it always goes to the weak symbol. Pls see the >code below for details.
>
> PS: Dont ask me to explain the reason particular sequence of execution, but I am open to >workarounds.
>
> foo_strong.c --> gcc -g -fPIC -shared -rdynamic foo_strong.o -o **libfoo_strong.so**
>
> foo.c: --> gcc -g -fPIC -shared -rdynamic -L/users/ardesiga/cprogs/ld_r foo.o -o **libfoo.so**
>
> app.c: --> gcc -g -fPIC -shared -rdynamic -L/users/ardesiga/cprogs/ld_r -lfoo -lfoo_strong app.o -o >     **libapp.so**

```
/* foo_strong.c */

int
foo_weak_func (char *msg)
{
    printf("[%s:%s] Reached strong, with msg: %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, msg);
}

/* foo.c */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "foo_ext.h"

#include "foo_weak.h"

int __attribute__ ((weak)) foo_weak_func (char *msg)
{
    printf("[%s:%s], Reached weak, with msg: %s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__, msg);
}

typedef int (*func_ptr_t) (char *msg);
func_ptr_t foo_func_ptr = foo_weak_func;

void
invoke_foo_func_ptr (char *msg)
{
    printf("Inside %s\n", __FUNCTION__);

    if (foo_func_ptr) {
        (*foo_func_ptr)(msg);
    } else {
        printf("foo_func_ptr is NULL\n");
    }
}


/* app.c */

#include "foo.h"

int
app_init_func (char *msg)
{
    printf("Inside %s:%s\n", __FILE__, __FUNCTION__);

    invoke_foo_func_ptr(msg);

}

/* main.c */

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *dl_handle;
    char *lib_name;
    app_init_func_t app_init_func;

    if (!(argc > 1)) {
        printf("Library is not supplied, loading libapp.so\n");
        lib_name = strdup("libapp.so");
    } else {
        lib_name = strdup(argv[2]);
    }

    printf("Loading library: %s\n", lib_name);

    dl_handle = dlopen(lib_name, RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!dl_handle) {
        printf("Failed to dlopen on %s, error: %s\n", lib_name, dlerror());
        exit(1);
    }

    app_init_func = dlsym(dl_handle, "app_init_func");
    if (app_init_func) {
        (*app_init_func)("Called via dlsym");
    } else {
        printf("dlsym did not file app_init_func");
    }

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

> My expectation is that invokes_foo_func_ptr invokes the strong symbol, but it always goes to the weak symbol.

Your expectation is incorrect and everything is working as designed.

Weak symbols lose to strong symbols when you link a single `ELF` binary. If you were to link a normal (strong) function `foo` and a weak `foo` into `libfoo.so`, the the strong definition would have won.

When you have *multiple* `ELF` images, some with strong `foo`, and some with weak `foo`, the *first* `ELF` image to define `foo` (regardless of whether weak or strong) wins. The loader will simply not look for any additional `ELF` images in its search scope once it finds the first image that does provide a definition for `foo`.

> Dont ask me to explain the reason particular sequence of execution

That is quite an obnoxious thing to say.

I have a guess as to what your reason may be, and a solution for it, but you'll have to provide your reason first.